# Magento 2 : Top menu count subcategories

Tags: magento2, category, topmenu

I have a top menu like **Parent > Category > Subcategories**.

I need to count the subcategories of category and **if > 4**, to show **All categories** as a link to the Category level. I have to mention that I am a newbie on Magento. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What will be the link for all categories?

Comment: It will be as the 5th subcategory and when I click on it, redirect to the up level category page.

Answer (score 2):

you have to create preference to override Topmenu Block file on custom modules like i have use Topmenu_module
/Topmenu/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type=" <your_namespace>\Topmenu\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

\Topmenu\Block\Html\Topmenu.php

```
<?php
namespace <your_namespace>\Topmenu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

protected function _getHtml(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
    $html = '';

    $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
    $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
    $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

    $counter = 1;
    $itemPosition = 1;
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
    $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? 
    $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child */
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
            continue;
        }
        $child->setLevel($childLevel);
        $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
        $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
        $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $currentClass = $child->getClass();

            if (empty($currentClass)) {
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            } else {
                $child->setClass($currentClass . ' ' . $outermostClass);
            }
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
            $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
        }
        if (!( $childLevel == 1 && $counter >= 5 )) {

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
            $child->getName()
        ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';

        } else {

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getParent()->getUrl() . '" ' . $parentPositionClass . '><span>show more</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>'; 
        break;  

        }
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;
    }

    if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
        $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}
}
```